# ¿Como evito que los caracteres utf-8 se escapen en la función json.dumps?

Tags: python, json, flask

Estoy haciendo un servidor donde sirvo mi página principal y un archivo JSON que contienen los productos disponibles o no disponibles:

```python
from flask import Flask;
import json;

app = Flask(__name__);
pds={};
with open("./database/productos.json","r") as f:
    pds=json.loads(f.read());
pds_available=json.dumps({"root":price["Available"]});
pds_navailable=json.dumps({"root":price["no Available"]});

@app.route("/products.json")
@app.route("/products.json?available=<int:post_id>",methods=['GET'])
def get_products(post_id=1):
    if not post_id==0:
        return pds_available;
    else:
        return pds_navailable;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    production="localhost";
    app.run(host=production, port=5000)
```

Voy a la `url` `products.json` y lo que me retorna tiene los caracteres `utf-8` escapado:

```JavaScript
{ "root": [ { "name": "Harina Do\u00c3\u00ba Belen", "value": 33}]}
```

Y lo que me gustaría:

```JavaScript
{ "root": [ { "name": "Harina Doña Belen", "value": 33}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la documentación oficial de `python` : https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Dice:

If `ensure_ascii` is true (the default), the output is guaranteed to have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. If `ensure_ascii` is false, these characters will be output as-is.

En el buen español:

Si `ensure_ascii` es verdadero (valor predeterminado), se garantiza que la salida tendrá todos los caracteres no ASCII escapados. Si `ensure_ascii` es falso, estos caracteres se mostrarán tal como están en la salida.

Por lo tanto:

```
json_ = json.dumps(js, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Ejemplo:

```
import json;

js = {"name": "Jabon de Baño", "value": 20}
json_ = json.dumps(js, ensure_ascii=False)
print(json_)
```

Genera:

```
{"name": "Jabon de Baño", "value": 20}
```